# How to .load to a php page an array?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How could I sent to a php page the array titolari?

```
var titolari = $('#titolari').sortable('toArray');
$("#formazione-realtime").load('formazione-realtime.inc.php', {
    "$titolari[]" : titolari
});
```

The php page is loaded correctly, but the php page seems not to receive the array... how do I take it into my php script?

Comment: The code you are showing is javascript, not PHP. Elaborate on your code (with more of the JS or PHP) and question please.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/), the call will use the POST method if data is added as an object.

On the client:

```
var titolari = $('#titolari').sortable('toArray');
$("#formazione-realtime").load('formazione-realtime.inc.php', {
    "titolari" : titolari
});
```

On the server:

```
$titolari = $_POST['titolari'];
```

Comment: Like this:
<?php
$titolari = $_GET['titolari'];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 300; $i++) {
    echo $titolari[$i];
}
?>
It doesn't echo anything...

Comment: Tommaso, my apologies! A bit down in the documentation I found this: "The POST method is used if data is provided as an object". I have updated my answer.

Comment: I'd like to specify that jQuery load formazione-realtime.inc.php, and this php page echos in the same page of jQuery. I don't know if it's a problem for _POST. And also titolari is an Array.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I know too little about jQuery to help you here. Maybe you can provide a full test case in your question?

Comment: just for test, this brings anything home?  $.post("formazione-realtime.inc.php",{"titolari" : titolari})

Comment: I've to correct: with ["titolari" : titolari] and [$titolari = $_POST['titolari'];] in the php page, if I echo $titolari, it prints "Array", but the array $titolari seems to be empty

Comment: Use `var_dump` or `print_r` when debugging arrays and objects. Just because `echo` says "Array" doesn't mean the array is empty.

Comment: I don't know if $.post("formazione-realtime.inc.php",{"titolari" : titolari}) get something, 'cause it doesn't echo anything in #formazione-realtime

Comment: So, how have I to modify the script to pass correctly titolaru array to formazione-realtime.php, so that it echos in #formazione-realtime?

Comment: Try using the developer tools available to your browser. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url:'formazione-realtime.inc.php',
    data:{
        'titolari':['ti','to','la','ri']
    },
    context:{},
    type:'POST',
    contentType:'json',
    success:function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#formazione-realtime").html(data);
    },
    error:function() {
        //Handle this
    }
};
```

PHP

```
try{
    $vars = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), 1);
catch(Exception $e) {
    //Handle this
}
print_r($vars);
exit;
```